# Moving Probability of Occurrences based on Success Rate

Tags: probability, ranking, data-analysis, moving-average

I want to implement a microservice that calculates the Success Rate of each Participant. This success rate is then used for evaluating their Probability of Occurrence, for instance, a Participant with higher success rate is more likely to get a task, and vice versa for the one with lowest success rate.

After a certain amount of time, the Probability of Occurrence will be re-evaluated based on Success Rates, and the process continues recursively.

What I have found so far:

- For calculating Success Rates, I am thinking of using **Exponentially Weighted Moving Average**
- In my scenario, the smoothing factor should be high (around 0.80-0.93).

What I am looking for:

- A reliable approach for the calculation of Success Rates with slower decay
- A reliable approach for evaluating the Probability of Occurrence and how tasks should be routed to each Participant.

> For more clarity, I'll try to explain this with an example:
>   Suppose there are 5 agents working in a call center. Now a call is received. The success rate of each agent for handling the calls and solving the query successfully is calculated. And then the call is routed to the best available choice in the pool. But, I don't want a single agent to handle all the calls. The calls should be routed to every agent, but the probability of routing the call to a certain agent should be based on his success rate calculated from the history. All agents will also be given a chance to improve their ranking iteratively after a certain amount of time.

Please suggest me some good approaches that I can look into.

Comment: A nice question after quite long...

Comment: Thanks @inquisitive

Comment: How many data points are we looking at? Tens? Hundreds? Thousands? Is the data in-memory or in database? Is this callcenter thing a good analogy or just a rough idea?

Comment: @inquisitive: Data points will be thousands currently but are likely to increase. Data is in the database. The call center is a good analogy as the example matches my requirement.

Comment: your intuition is good. you may want to checkout [proportionally fair scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionally_fair). this will do exactly what you want.

Comment: @miraculixx: Thanks. Weighted fair queuing sounds like a good approach to me. I'll surely look into it.

Comment: There is no one right answer to this problem. There are many similar approach with slightly different tradeoffs. For example, lets say you have two agents A and B with 50% and 100% success rates respectively. So incoming jobs get distributed in a 1:2 ratio. A gets 1/3 and B gets 2/3 of total jobs. Good. Now lets say we have a third agent C with 50% suvcess rate. In this new system, what should be the ratio of distribution? (Approach 1) 1/6:1/6:2/3 or (Approach 2) 1/4:1/4:2/4? This is a business problem, not technical. Once this is sorted out, technical can be handled.

Comment: @inquisitive: Correct. That's where I need suggestions. So, the distributions will not be that simple. A with success rate 50%, B with 100% and C with 50% and total data points 1000, should results into a distribution that looks something like 3/10,4/10,3/10 approx. After a certain period of time, B improves his success rate to 80%, A to 60%, C to 50%, then B should experience a slight improvement in the distribution at the cost of A's distribution, while C remains the same. In this way, everyone will get a fair chance to improve their rankings.

Comment: More specifically, (Approach 1) For an incoming job, every agent competes only with its peers. The peers can be the agents with equal or similar credits. So for an agent, his probability changes only only when other agents compete directly. In (Approach 2) Every agent competes with every other agent, though with weightage. So for an agent, his probability changes also when other agents appear or improve. Think of this way, there is one good agent and lots of bad agents. What should be the distribution? This will give the algo.